# how to compare two dictionaries to check if a key is present in both of them

Tags: python

I am trying to compare two dictionaries and check if each key in dict1 is present(or not) in either of dict2 or dict3 using the below logic? Is there a better way to check if any of the keys in dict1 are present in dict2 or dict3 and get the corresponding value?

```
dict1 = {'1234': 'john','5678': 'james'};
dict2 = {'1234': 'technician'};
dict3 = {'5678': '50.23'};

shared_keys1 = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)

shared_keys2 = set(dict1).intersection(dict3)

for key in shared_keys1:
    print( "Found Shared Key:{0}".format(key) )
    print( "dict1['{0}']={1}".format(key,dict2[key]) )


for key in shared_keys2:
    print( "Found Shared Key:{0}".format(key) )
    print( "dict1['{0}']={1}".format(key,dict3[key]) )
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Found Shared Key:1234
dict1['1234']=technici
Found Shared Key:5678
dict1['5678']=50.23
```

Comment: You are just "checking" if key is present in `dict2`, not if it is present in `dict1` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`in` on a `dict` will return if a key is present in a dictionary:

```
>>> a = {'b': 1, 'c': '2'}
>>> 'b' in a
True
>>> 'd' in a
False
```

So your code could be written as:

```
dict1 = {'1234': 'john','5678': 'james'};
dict2 = {'1234': 'technician'};

for key in dict1.keys():
    print key
    if key in dict2:
        print dict1[key] + dict2[key]
    else:
        print dict1[key]
```

If you just want to check that the two are equal, you can do:

```
set(dict1) == set(dict2)
```

Comment: that wont check if they are equal ... only if all the keys are shared

Comment: The title of the question is 'how to compare two dictionaries to check if a key is present in both of them', so I was assuming it's the keys that are important.

Comment: thats not an unreasonable interpretation

Comment: @AlexTaylor - how to check for more than one dictionary ,something like `if key in (dict2,dict3):`

Comment: @PythonProg `if key in set().union(*list_of_dicts):` is not efficient but will allow you to provide an arbitrarily long list of dicts to test.

Answer (score 5):

```
shared_keys = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
```

is how I would do it

```
>>> dict1 = {'1234': 'john','5678': 'james'}
>>> dict2 = {'1234': 'technician'};
>>> set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
set(['1234'])


>>> if set(dict1).intersection(dict2):
...     print "there is at least one key that is present in both dictionaries..."
...
there is at least one key that is present in both dictionaries...
```

if you wanted to check more dicts you just add them

```
shared_keys = set(dict1).intersection(dict2).intersection(dict3)


for key in shared_keys:
    print( "Found Shared Key:{0}".format(key) )
    print( "dict1['{0}']={1}".format(key,dict1[key]) )
    print( "dict2['{0}']={1}".format(key,dict2[key]) )
    print( "dict3['{0}']={1}".format(key,dict3[key]) )
```

Comment: Joran - This wont help me, I dont need the shared keys,i need to know for any key present in dict1 is present in dict2 or not

Comment: Joran - how does this work for 3 dictionaries,lets say I have dict1,dict2,dict3.I want to check if each of the keys in present in dict2 or dict3? and how to know out of dict2 and dict3 where the key is present to get the corresponding value

Comment: I edited my answer at the same second you added your comment

Comment: I think you should probably look into some basic python tutorials about what dictionaries are and what keys are and what sets are ... theres only so much of your homework or whatever this is that people are going to hold your hand through on stackoverflow

Comment: I have the latest code and query updated,I was probably not clear in my earlier comments

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in dict1:
    try:
        print dict1[key] + dict2[key]
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Your first function doesn't need to take key or dict1 as parameters. I don't think its doing what you want it to do either. That `for` should probably be an `if`. It could be re-written as:

```
def key_ispresent_in_dict2(key, dict2):
    if key in dict2.keys():
        return True
    return False
```

You are on the right track and could re-write the whole thing as:

```
dict1 = {'1234': 'john','5678': 'james'};
dict2 = {'1234': 'technician'};

for key in dict1.keys():
    print key
    if key in dict2.keys():
        print dict1[key] + dict2[key]
    else:
        print dict1[key]
```

and completly get rid of `key_ispresent_in_dict2`